# Filter created_at with 3 functions by parsing DateTime rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

currently i am getting values from database with a query

```
created_ats = Snapshot.connection.select_all("SELECT created_at from snapshots WHERE snapshot_id >= '#{camera_id}_#{from_date}' AND snapshot_id <= '#{camera_id}_#{to_date}'")
```

This query is giving me all `created_ats` according to conditions.

i want to filter all these `created_ats` according to some inputs which users have been passed to database which are

days and times

```
"{"Monday":["3:0-7:0","15:0-17:30"],"Tuesday":[],"Wednesday":["11:0-16:0"],"Thursday":["5:0-10:0"],"Friday":["15:30-22:30"],"Saturday":[],"Sunday":[]}"
```

its just an example days and times are can be totally filled or partially.

there is a field named as `INTERVAL`. which is being considered as MINUTES.
Now what is the whole scenario, from query i am getting created_at which is general `timestamps` in ruby on rails.

i want to filter those `created_at` with the giving Days and timings provided along with everyday in info above. + adding X(interval) to that created at as well.

such as after refining between days and timings. we will have a list of created_ats so after that starting from first created_at will add x.minutes in that created at and will assure that (created_at+x.minutes) is also present in created_ats(which we got after days and hours refining), is YESS then save it else leave it.

what i have tried so far is this and its not working as i want it to work according to me it seems no error in that but still dont give me specific value

```
class SnapshotExtractor < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "evercam_db_#{Rails.env}".to_sym

    belongs_to :camera
    require "rmega"
    require "aws-sdk-v1"
    require 'open-uri'

  def self.connect_mega
    storage = Rmega.login("#{ENV['MEGA_EMAIL']}", "#{ENV['MEGA_PASSWORD']}")
    storage
  end

  def self.connect_bucket
    access_key_id = "#{ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']}"
    secret_access_key = "#{ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']}"
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(
      access_key_id: access_key_id,
      secret_access_key: secret_access_key,
    )
    bucket = s3.buckets["evercam-camera-assets"]
    bucket
  end
  # def self.test
        # snapshot_bucket = connect_bucket
        # storage = connect_mega
        # folder = storage.root.create_folder("dongi")
        # s3_object = snapshot_bucket.objects["gpo-cam/snapshots/1452136326.jpg"]
        # snap_url = s3_object.url_for(:get, {expires: 1.years.from_now, secure: true}).to_s
        # File.open("formula.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(snap_url) }
        # open('image.jpg', 'wb') do |file|
        #   file << open(snap_url).read
        # end
        # folder.upload("image.jpg")
  # end
    def self.extract_snapshots
        running = SnapshotExtractor.where(status: 1).any?
        unless running
            @snapshot_request = SnapshotExtractor.where(status: 0).first
            @snapshot_request.update_attribute(:status, 1)
            camera_id = @snapshot_request.camera_id
            exid = Camera.find(camera_id).exid
            mega_id = @snapshot_request.id
            from_date = @snapshot_request.from_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            to_date = @snapshot_request.to_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            interval = @snapshot_request.interval
            @days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
            set_days = []
            set_timings = []

            index = 0
            @days.each do |day|
                if @snapshot_request.schedule[day].present?
                    set_days[index] = day
                    set_timings[index] = @snapshot_request.schedule[day]
                    index += 1
                end
            end

            begin
                created_ats = Snapshot.connection.select_all("SELECT created_at from snapshots WHERE snapshot_id >= '#{camera_id}_#{from_date}' AND snapshot_id <= '#{camera_id}_#{to_date}'")
                created_at_spdays = refine_days(created_ats, set_days)
                created_at_sptime = refine_times(created_at_spdays, set_timings, set_days)
                created_at = refine_intervals(created_at_sptime, interval)
                File.open("test.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(created_at) }
                storage = connect_mega
                creatp = storage.root.create_folder("created_at")
                creatp.upload("test.txt")
            rescue => error
                notify_airbrake(error)
            end

            begin
                storage = connect_mega
                snapshot_bucket = connect_bucket
                new_folder = storage.root.create_folder("#{exid}")
                folder = storage.nodes.find do |node|
                  node.type == :folder and node.name == "#{exid}"
                end
                folder.create_folder("#{mega_id}")
                created_at.each do |snap|
                    snap_i = DateTime.parse(snap).to_i
                    s3_object = snapshot_bucket.objects["#{exid}/snapshots/#{snap_i}.jpg"]
                    if s3_object.exists?
                        snap_url = s3_object.url_for(:get, {expires: 1.years.from_now, secure: true}).to_s
                        File.open("formula_#{snap_i}.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(snap_url) }
                        open('#{snap_i}.jpg', 'wb') do |file|
                          file << open(snap_url).read
                        end
                        folder.upload('#{snap_i}.jpg')
                    end
                end
                @snapshot_request.update_attribute(:status, 3)
            rescue => error
                error
            end     
        end
        # created_at
    end

    private

    def self.refine_days(created_ats, days)
        created_at = []
        index = 0
        created_ats.each do |single|
            days.each do |day|
                if day == Date.parse(single["created_at"]).strftime("%A")
                    created_at[index] = single["created_at"]
                    index += 1
                end
            end
        end
        created_at
    end

    def self.refine_times(created_ats, timings, days)
        created_at = []
        index = 0
        day_index = 0
        days_times =  days.zip(timings.flatten)
        one = 1
        zero = 0
        created_ats.each do |single|
            days_times.each do |day_time|
                if Date.parse(single).strftime("%A") == day_time[day_index]
                    start_time = DateTime.parse(day_time[one].split("-")[zero]).strftime("%H:%M")
                    end_time = DateTime.parse(day_time[one].split("-")[one]).strftime("%H:%M")
                    created_at_time = DateTime.parse(single).strftime("%H:%M")
                    if created_at_time >= start_time && created_at_time <= end_time
                        created_at[index] = single
                        index += 1
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        created_at
    end

    def self.refine_intervals(created_ats, interval)
        created_at = [created_ats.first]
        last_created_at = DateTime.parse(created_ats.last)
        index = 1
        index_for_dt = 0
        length = created_ats.length
        (1..length).each do |single|
            if (DateTime.parse(created_at[index_for_dt]) + interval.minutes) <= last_created_at
                temp = DateTime.parse(created_at[index_for_dt]) + interval.minutes
                created_at[index] = temp.to_s
                index_for_dt += 1
                index += 1
            end
        end
        created_at
    end
end
```

Comment: You're circumventing the SQL escaping method available in Rails and this is **very bad**. You should be using placeholder values, like `snapshot_id >= ?` and then add `'#{camera_id}_#{from_date}'` to the function call. There's also no need to use the low-level connection object when [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) is available and does the job in a much cleaner way.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `"#{x}"` is almost always pointless and should be `x` instead, and you're using this anti-pattern extensively in your code for no apparent reason. For example, you should say just: `Rmega.login(ENV['MEGA_EMAIL'], ENV['MEGA_PASSWORD'])`. If you need to convert to a string, `x.to_s` is the most standard way to do this and it makes your intent clear.

Comment: sorry for all this mess, can i have your answer on that please?

Comment: It's not clear quite what your question is, so I just offered that advice to clean it up and maybe get more to the core of it.

Comment: Questions is you can leave ENV and the query only consider timestamps-> created_at and then filter it through days and times. and add intervel as wel